# Looking for French Media Bias Chart

Tags: media, france

Can anyone point me to a reliable French Media Bias Chart, please? I am looking for an equivalent of [adfontes media bias chart](https://www.adfontesmedia.com/?v=402f03a963ba) for French media.

Comment: Beleive me or not, the french government is planning to create its own media biased chart : http://www.leparisien.fr/culture-loisirs/tv/le-site-anti-fake-news-du-gouvernement-fait-grincer-des-dents-02-05-2020-8309730.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is unfortunately still no adfontes-style, comprehensive graphic in reference to the French media. However, there have been a number of studies analyzing the French public's perception of the media as well as media consumption habits along political cleavages.

For instance, the best source for your inquiry might be [this Pew Research article](https://www.pewresearch.org/global/fact-sheet/news-media-and-political-attitudes-in-france/) which measures perceptions of the media and should give you an idea as to the perceived bias of the French media. From there, you might have to interpolate.

See also [this](https://www.scoop.it/topic/media-pub-et-digital/p/4019279198/2014/04/09/quelle-est-la-couleur-politique-des-medias) graphic from the French publication "Marianne," which shows which outlets are preferred by those who place themselves on the political left and right.